# How can I track TreasuryDirect savings bonds with Mint?

Tags: bonds, expense-tracking, mint.com, treasury

I have a pair of Series I Savings Bonds with TreasuryDirect. Is it possible to track their value using Mint? If so, what's the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mint cannot connect with TreasuryDirect to track savings bonds. But, you can [manually add the value of the bonds as "other property" in Mint](http://help.mint.com/General/888960251/How-do-I-add-a-manual-account-in-Mint.htm) and update it manually on a monthly basis (when the value of the bonds change).

You can get the value of the bonds directly from the TreasuryDirect website, or through their savings bond wizard application.

Comment: [Mint doesn't seem to have a category for bonds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6NMJ.png). Any recommendations for what category to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value of the bonds to property under the "other" category. I selected "Miscellaneous Items" and then added the name of the bond for the label that mint asks you to fill out. hope this helps.

Comment: You should probably add a screenshot and/or a link to the official documentation. User interfaces on websites tend to change over time.

Answer (score -2):

This functionality only works via their website. Not on the mobile version.

Comment: I'm not using the mobile version. How do you track TreasuryDirect bonds on the website?